# Using double-quote character in Sed

Tags: sed

I have a variable with a value double quote in it, i need to do a search on a file and eliminate the line that has the values matching in the variable.

I need to take the line that has name="logisticsUnitHeight" from below

Input:

```
Row starts
<attrQual name="logisticsUnitHeight" 
row1
row2     
/attrQual>
```

Output

Row Starts

row1

row2

/attrQual>

The row that has the matching pattern is to be deleted.

Comment: Where's the code, sample input, and expected output?

Comment: I need to take the line that has name="logisticsUnitHeight" from below                   <attrQual name="logisticsUnitHeight" qual="CMT">95.7</attrQual>
<attrQual name="logisticsUnitDepth" qual="CMT">120</attrQual>

Comment: @Parthi Please update the text of the question with all relevant information rather than leaving it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
needle='something"withaquote'
sed "/$needle/d" /path/to/haystack
```

or

```
needle='something"withaquote'
grep -v "$needle" /path/to/haystack
```

or

```
awk -v needle='/something"withaquote/' '$0 !~ needle {print}' /path/to/haystack
```

Comment: needle='something "with double quote"to be removed'

Comment: Still works as described.

Comment: sed -i "/$ATTR7/,/$ATTR8/d" $VAL          This is the command i use , in that  ATTR7 =  <attrQualMany name="languageSpecificBrandName">   and  ATTR8 = /attrQualMany>

Comment: @Parthi Your command is different than your main question.You might think that your problem is the double quote , but looking at what you tried your problems seems to related not to double quotes but to incorrect use of sed. Edit your question, include correct input data, include expected output, include what you tried and what error message you get with your try.

Comment: yes, i have done that now, pls let me know further changes